# NetBeans Remote Connection

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to set netBeans remote project and I'm having pretty much trouble with it. I've started a PHP Application from Remote Server and in the last confirmation step it throws error on me.

> No files available for download. Try to check Passive mode in the remote configuration.

In the log output it fails there:

```
> 215 UNIX Type: L8
> PORT 192,168,5,217,196,73
> 500 Illegal PORT command.
```

Did anyone have same problem with setting up remote connection? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To establish an FTP connection, choose either of the options below:

- Turn off the Windows firewall.
- Configure Windows Firewall for a passive mode FTP server as follows:

  1. Open an Administrator command-prompt.
  2. Click Start > All Programs > Accessories.
  3. Right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.
  4. Run the following command:

     ```
     netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=FTPService action=allow service=ftpsvc protocol=TCP dir=in
     ```
  5. Disable stateful FTP filtering so that the firewall does not block any FTP traffic:

     ```
     netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
     ```

Comment: That was the thing that got me running a few years ago :D. Found it somewhere else.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 using NetBeans 8.2. Thanks. +1.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well on windows 10 .. thanks

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be the top answer whenever anyone is looking for how to set netbeans into passive mode. Despite the advice always being "set the ftp into passive mode" for those using Mac OS and Netbeans you may never seem to find it.

1. Right click on the project
2. Select Properties
3. Select Run Configurations
4. Select Manage
5. Select your_ftp_connection on the left column
6. Scroll down

[image: NetBeans FTP Connection]

Answer (score 3):

The only way I fixed this was to switch to using SFTP. This obviously requires that you've set up SFTP (FTP over SSH) access to your server.

In the Run Configuration, when it asks you for the Remote Connection:

1. Click on 'Manage'
2. Click on 'Add...'
3. Select SFTP as the connection type
4. Fill in the rest of the details as if it were a normal FTP connection.

Answer (score 3):

Turning plain FTP Netbeans connection into passive mode solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please Check **Passive Mode**; i had faced the same issue; after checking it; resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find the passive mode in a OSX. It's a Netbeans bug... So I won't be able to develop on netbeans using my Mac. Already tried to download last version.

Comment: Really? Have you checked [Kenny West's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28935977/3982001)?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to check **Passive Mode** on the client and to do following things on the server side

in /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_max_port=10100
pasv_min_port=10090
```

then in terminal

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 10090:10100 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service vsftpd restart
```