# Cant open php files in Netbeans with Filezilla

Tags: php, netbeans-8, filezilla

I have a mac system and have installed NetBeans 8.0.2 in it.
When I try to edit PHP file from FileZill into the NetBeans it just opens NetBeans but can't load the file into the NetBeans

Any help will be thankful.

Comment: if you use netbeans no need to use filezilla , netbeans have own FTP client , Try to use netbeans FTP client

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515872/netbeans-remote-connection